# Angular form submit only has fields with changes - not the full form values

Tags: angular, observable, angular-forms

When i submit my angular form i get values only for changed fields. I should be getting the full form values correct?

```
 // Profile.html
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="submitProfileForm(profileForm.value)" #myform="ngForm">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" value="{{currentUserMeta.firstName}}" formControlName='firstName'>

 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" formControlName='lastName'value="{{currentUserMeta.lastName}}">
....
</form>

// Profile.ts
submitProfileForm(value: any) {
    console.log(this.profileForm.get('firstName').value);
    console.log(this.profileForm.get('lastName').value);
    console.log(value);
    this.userService.updateUserProfile(value);
}
```

When I change only the about input field for example and then press submit I get this in the output.

```
{displayName: "", firstName: "", lastName: "", about: "12"}
```

firstName and lastName had values and they were grabbed from an observable *currentUserMeta*

It seems to me the form is not aware when these values got updated through angular binding {{ }}.

### another example

form initial state (Correct)

[image]

after pressing 2 for lastName and 3 for about field and then pressing Submit

[image]

As you can see firstName value of 1 is not there in the log. And even trying to print it out through log is not working.

```
 console.log(this.profileForm.get('firstName').value);
```

I should add that I get all the values(changed and unchanged) if the form is already loaded and I updated all of the inputs at one time or another. (I dont redirect to another page after submit). Let me know if I have done something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aproach is not 100% fine, it seams that you are using **ModelDrivenForm** and passing the value which is more like **TemplateDrivenForm**.

If you use **ModelDrivenForm**, like it seams that is what you are using, is fine how you are declaring the form's `[formGroup]` and the input's `formControlName` but you shuldn't put the predefined values in `value="{{currentUserMeta.lastName}}"`

You shuld set these values in your ts file, using for example `this.profileForm.get('lastName').set(this.currentUserMeta.lastName);` when you have this data.

I hope that this helps, more info about ModelDrivenForms are here in the doc https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms and about template-driven form are here https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: you are right! its described here. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

since the data source is observable I am thinking to set the values in a subscribe in ngOnInit() as such. Do you see any problem with this? 
 this.currentUserMeta.subscribe((data) => {
      this.profileForm.get('lastName').setValue(data.lastName);
    });

Comment: I don't see any problem with that, and if in that subscribe you get in data the two needed values what you can do to set both of them at once is tu use patchValue() like this:

this.currentUserMeta.subscribe((data) => { 
    this.profileForm.patchValue(
       {
           firstName: data.firstName
           lastName: data.lastName
        });
});